# error: illegal start expression. when placing a final string` statement in the `public static void main` method

Tags: java, final, main-method

I have just started learning Java a few weeks ago. I'm trying to learn the key word final in java language. I wrote a `final string` statement in the `public static void main` method. However, the IDE is displaying the error: illegal start expression. However, the IDE did not provide any additional information. Because I'm relatively new to Java, I am unable to understand why this is happening. Could someone please explain the reason to me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    private final String s1 = "hello world";
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you so much for helping out? May I ask why we can't put private keyword within a method?

Comment: Ask yourself, what would it mean? The variable is local to he method regardless and cannot be seen outside of the method scope, so adding a `private` modifier would be senseless.

Comment: that make sense. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `private` field within a method, and this only makes sense within class scope, not method scope. Get rid of the `private` modifier.

To get a handle on this, ask yourself, what would it mean? The variable `s1` is local to he method regardless and so cannot be seen outside of the method scope, so adding a `private` modifier would be senseless as it wouldn't change anything.